# Matrix Multiplication using divide&conquer

Tags: c, malloc, matrix-multiplication

I am working on a code to perform matrix multiplication using divide&conquer method. My code goes as this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 8  //Able to change size

void add(int **a, int **b, int size, int **c)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            c[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void subtract(int **a, int **b, int size, int **c)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            c[i][j]=a[i][j]-b[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void multiply(int **c, int **d, int size, int **result)
{
    if(size==1)
    {
        result[0][0]=c[0][0]*d[0][0]; /*Could this base case calculation be wrong?*/
    }
    else
    {
        int i, j;
        int new_size=size/2;

        int **c11=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            c11[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **c12=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            c12[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **c21=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            c21[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **c22=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            c22[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **d11=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            d11[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **d12=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            d12[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **d21=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            d21[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **d22=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            d22[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }

        int **temp1=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            temp1[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **temp2=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            temp2[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **temp3=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            temp3[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **temp4=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            temp4[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **temp5=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            temp4[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **temp6=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            temp6[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **temp7=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            temp7[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **temp8=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            temp8[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }

        int **res1=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            res1[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **res2=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            res2[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **res3=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            res3[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }
        int **res4=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            res4[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
        }

        for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<new_size; j++)
            {
                c11[i][j]=c[i][j];
                c12[i][j]=c[i][j+new_size];
                c21[i][j]=c[i+new_size][j];
                c22[i][j]=c[i+new_size][j+new_size];
                d11[i][j]=d[i][j];
                d12[i][j]=d[i][j+new_size];
                d21[i][j]=d[i+new_size][j];
                d22[i][j]=d[i+new_size][j+new_size];
            }
        }

        multiply(c11, d11, new_size, temp1);
        multiply(c12, d21, new_size, temp2);
        multiply(c11, d12, new_size, temp3);
        multiply(c12, d22, new_size, temp4);
        multiply(c21, d11, new_size, temp5);
        multiply(c22, d21, new_size, temp6);
        multiply(c21, d12, new_size, temp7);
        multiply(c22, d22, new_size, temp8);
        add(temp1, temp2, new_size, res1);
        add(temp3, temp4, new_size, res2);
        add(temp5, temp6, new_size, res3);
        add(temp7, temp8, new_size, res4);

        int x=0;
        int y=0;
        int z=0;
        int w=0;
        for(i=0; i<2*new_size; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<2*new_size; j++)
            {
                if(i<new_size && j<new_size)
                {
                    result[i][j]=res1[i][j];
                }
                if(i<new_size && j>=new_size)
                {
                    x=j-new_size;
                    result[i][j]=res2[i][x];
                }
                if(i>=new_size && j<new_size)
                {
                    y=i-new_size;
                    result[i][j]=res3[y][j];
                }
                if(i>=new_size && j>=new_size)
                {
                    z=i-new_size;
                    w=j-new_size;
                    result[i][j]=res4[z][w];
                }
            }
        }
    free(c11);
    free(c12);
    free(c21);
    free(c22);
    free(d11);
    free(d12);  
    free(d21);  
    free(d22);
    free(temp1);
    free(temp2);
    free(temp3);
    free(temp4);
    free(temp5);
    free(temp6);
    free(temp7);
    free(temp8);
    free(res1);
    free(res2);
    free(res3);
    free(res4);
    }
}

int main(void)
{   
    int i, j;

    int **A=(int **)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        A[i]=(int *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
    }
    int **B=(int **)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        B[i]=(int *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
    }
    int **C=(int **)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        C[i]=(int *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
    }

    int count=0;
    int sum=0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            A[i][j]=rand()%1000;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            B[i][j]=rand()%1000;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            C[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%5d", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%5d", B[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    multiply(A, B, SIZE, C);

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%5d", C[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);

}
```

The code is meant to generate random two n*n matrices, split the big matrices into half, and multiply the submatrices recursively as you might know. After the calculation I display the result of the multiplication. I put the calculated submatrices in the result matrix.

I've tried using debuggers, but the program just quits after a few moments. From my former experience, I suspect that there might be some problems with the initialization of variables, but it seems fine to me at this moment.

Could anyone point out what I've missed? Sorry for the redundant mallocs in the middle. I'm going to make a function after I find the code is properly working. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I diagnosed this by compiling with debugging enabled and optimization disabled, and running in a debugger. The debugger showed a fault on a statement `result[0][0]=c[0][0]*d[0][0]` in the routine `multiply`. In the debugger, I printed `c`, `c[0]`, `d`, `d[0]`, `result`, and `result[0]` to see which one was problematic. This revealed `result[0]` was zero. I then looked for each call to `multiply` and inserted a `printf` statement to print `x[0]`, where `x` is what was being passed to `multiply` for the `result` parameter. This revealed that `temp5` had not been set.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains:

```
    int **temp5=(int **)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0; i<new_size; i++)
    {
        temp4[i]=(int *)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int));
    }
```

`temp4` is a typo; the contents of `temp5[i]` are never set.